# UUID shortening

Tags: java, redis, uuid

I need to calculate the daily number of unique users of an app.

The only way I can uniquely identify a user is via their UUID (this is externally supplied so I am forced to use it).

I know that my daily user counts are a couple of million users.

I'd like to use a bitset in Redis to do a population count, but in order for this to work, I'd need a way of narrowing my UUID so that it could comfortably fit into a long. I am aware of the potential for collisions but I am not concerned about precise numbers.

Has anyone done this in Java before? What I am after is how I could convert my UUID into something that could fit into a long.

Answer (score 3):

There are two methods on the [`UUID`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) object which might benefit you.

[`getLeastSignificantBits()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#getLeastSignificantBits%28%29) and [`getMostSignificateBits()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#getMostSignificantBits%28%29). Both return a long. Take one of these longs as your answer (or some kind of combination if you care.)

Comment: I would combine the two values using `^` (xor) or something similar if you're using the built-in Java version that puts the time in one value and the node and clock sequence in the other.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I have discovered the long returned from getLeastSignificantBits() and getMostSignificantBits() is still too large a value to be used in Redis bitsets.

Comment: Take the output from one of these and mask it to cut down the number of bits. How many bits are you allowed?

Answer (score 3):

you could generate a hash of your uuids that generates ints or longs and use those for your population count.

have a look a `redis.clients.util.MurmurHash' in the jedis redis library. you can find it at https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis

*edit: sample

```
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(16).putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits()).putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
        buf.flip();
        int useMe= MurmurHash.hash(buf, 123);
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas. I assume using something like MurmurHash has a risk (presumably low?) of collisions?

I noticed in your example you put a seed value of 123. Is this a suitable value for hashing a UUID?

Comment: Hi seedhead, sorry for the late answer but here it goes: Every hashing algo has the risk of collisions, but since you're doing a population count you should be fine. The redis lib uses '0x1234ABCD' as seed which should be fine

Answer (score 2):

This is probably small enough to fit directly using the full UUID as a hash key.  Approximations can also be made using [less memory](http://highscalability.com/blog/2012/4/5/big-data-counting-how-to-count-a-billion-distinct-objects-us.html) if that suites your needs.