# Generate Checksum for String

Tags: string, algorithm, checksum

I would like to Generate Checksum for Strings/Data

```
1. The same data should produce the same Checksum
2. Two different data strings can't product same checksum. Random collision of 0.1% can be negligible
3. No encryption/decryption of data 
4. Checksum length need not be too huge and contains letters and characters.
5. Must be too fast and efficient. Imagine generating checksum(s) for 100 Mb of text data should be in less than 5mins. Generating 1000 checksums for less than 1 KB of each segment data should be in less than 10 seconds.
```

Any algorithm or implementation reference and suggestions are most appreciated.

Comment: Use hashing...if you can't encrypt/decrypt.

Comment: @vish4071, better suggest some hashing technique than "use hashing".

Comment: Sha-1, Sha-2, MD5...etc. Or define a custom hashing function. (Also...you could be less rude).

Comment: If a 0.1% collision tolerance means that there needs to be only 1000 possible checksums, then the sum can occupy 10 bits (2^10 = 1024). A very simple, very fast checksum can be performed by just adding all bytes modulo 16.

Comment: @sifferman, what if I want to increase the collision tolerance by 10 factor more. I would like to understand different algos, so that one can be picked up by evaluating performance vs tolerance

Comment: To improve it by a factor of 10, you need 10 more bits, or 20 bits. A very common, very fast checksum is the CRC-32, which uses 32 bits.

Comment: Adding all bytes % 16 would result in a set of 16 hashes in total...Also, adding is not a very good hash.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I meant modulo 65536.

Comment: But still, `stop`, `tops` and `pots` will result in same hash.

Comment: Yes they will, but his requirement was 0.1%. Those (and `opts` and `post` too!) will fall within that tolerance. His question suggested he wanted it fast, and was willing to accept a 0.1% collision tolerance.

Comment: Take a look at Murmur hash, it has very low collision rate and acceptable (for my case) performance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899616/murmurhash-what-is-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very common, fast checksum is the CRC-32, a 32-bit polynomial cyclic redundancy check. Here are three implementations in C, which vary in speed vs. complexity, of the CRC-32: (This is from http://www.hackersdelight.org/hdcodetxt/crc.c.txt)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// ---------------------------- reverse --------------------------------

// Reverses (reflects) bits in a 32-bit word.
unsigned reverse(unsigned x) {
   x = ((x & 0x55555555) <<  1) | ((x >>  1) & 0x55555555);
   x = ((x & 0x33333333) <<  2) | ((x >>  2) & 0x33333333);
   x = ((x & 0x0F0F0F0F) <<  4) | ((x >>  4) & 0x0F0F0F0F);
   x = (x << 24) | ((x & 0xFF00) << 8) |
       ((x >> 8) & 0xFF00) | (x >> 24);
   return x;
}

// ----------------------------- crc32a --------------------------------

/* This is the basic CRC algorithm with no optimizations. It follows the
logic circuit as closely as possible. */

unsigned int crc32a(unsigned char *message) {
   int i, j;
   unsigned int byte, crc;

   i = 0;
   crc = 0xFFFFFFFF;
   while (message[i] != 0) {
      byte = message[i];            // Get next byte.
      byte = reverse(byte);         // 32-bit reversal.
      for (j = 0; j <= 7; j++) {    // Do eight times.
         if ((int)(crc ^ byte) < 0)
              crc = (crc << 1) ^ 0x04C11DB7;
         else crc = crc << 1;
         byte = byte << 1;          // Ready next msg bit.
      }
      i = i + 1;
   }
   return reverse(~crc);
}

// ----------------------------- crc32b --------------------------------

/* This is the basic CRC-32 calculation with some optimization but no
table lookup. The the byte reversal is avoided by shifting the crc reg
right instead of left and by using a reversed 32-bit word to represent
the polynomial.
   When compiled to Cyclops with GCC, this function executes in 8 + 72n
instructions, where n is the number of bytes in the input message. It
should be doable in 4 + 61n instructions.
   If the inner loop is strung out (approx. 5*8 = 40 instructions),
it would take about 6 + 46n instructions. */

unsigned int crc32b(unsigned char *message) {
   int i, j;
   unsigned int byte, crc, mask;

   i = 0;
   crc = 0xFFFFFFFF;
   while (message[i] != 0) {
      byte = message[i];            // Get next byte.
      crc = crc ^ byte;
      for (j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {    // Do eight times.
         mask = -(crc & 1);
         crc = (crc >> 1) ^ (0xEDB88320 & mask);
      }
      i = i + 1;
   }
   return ~crc;
}

// ----------------------------- crc32c --------------------------------

/* This is derived from crc32b but does table lookup. First the table
itself is calculated, if it has not yet been set up.
Not counting the table setup (which would probably be a separate
function), when compiled to Cyclops with GCC, this function executes in
7 + 13n instructions, where n is the number of bytes in the input
message. It should be doable in 4 + 9n instructions. In any case, two
of the 13 or 9 instrucions are load byte.
   This is Figure 14-7 in the text. */

unsigned int crc32c(unsigned char *message) {
   int i, j;
   unsigned int byte, crc, mask;
   static unsigned int table[256];

   /* Set up the table, if necessary. */

   if (table[1] == 0) {
      for (byte = 0; byte <= 255; byte++) {
         crc = byte;
         for (j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {    // Do eight times.
            mask = -(crc & 1);
            crc = (crc >> 1) ^ (0xEDB88320 & mask);
         }
         table[byte] = crc;
      }
   }

   /* Through with table setup, now calculate the CRC. */

   i = 0;
   crc = 0xFFFFFFFF;
   while ((byte = message[i]) != 0) {
      crc = (crc >> 8) ^ table[(crc ^ byte) & 0xFF];
      i = i + 1;
   }
   return ~crc;
}
```

If you simply [google "CRC32"](https://www.google.com/search?q=crc32&oq=crc32), you will get more info than you could possibly absorb.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom hash function: (c++)

```
long long int hash(String s){
    long long k = 7;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        k *= 23;
        k += s[i];
        k *= 13;
        k %= 1000000009;
    }
    return k;
}
```

This should give you a well (collision free for most samples) hash value.

Comment: multiplication with 23 and 13 are randomly or is there any logic behind it?