# Uniform distribution of hashcode()

Tags: java, hashcode, hash-collision

I define my class as:

```
final class Key<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private final T q;
    private final T o;
    public Key(T q1, T o1) {
        q = q1;
        o = o1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj != null && obj instanceof Key) {
            Key<T> s = (Key<T>)obj;
            return q.equals(s.q) && o.equals(s.o);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(q,o);
    }
}
```

I also define an array to contain object key . For example:

```
Object arr[] = new Object[100];
Key<String> k = new Key<>("a","b");
int h = k.hashcode();
...
arr[h+i % h] = k; //i from 1 to 10 for example
```

The problem is that hashcode() can return a negative value so

```
arr[h+i % h] = k;
```

can return an error out of array index. That's why I changed my code as(based on my searching for avoiding hashcode() return negative value):

```
@Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return (Objects.hash(q,o)&0x7FFFFFFF);
        }
```

So if I do this way, does a uniform distribution of the hashcode() be changed or not? I mean the probability to have a same value from two different objects will be increased or not?

Comment: Yes, my error. I also edited it. Thanks

Comment: you can have a look at murmur hash which has very good distribution. and cant be negetive value as well

Answer (score 2):

The `Object.hash()` has a very simple hashCode which is not particularly uniform for simple examples. e.g. Objects.hash("B", "B") and Objects.hash("A", "a") have the same hashCode. (And BTW simple enough that I could work that out in my head)

Also every between `Objects.hashCode("a", "a")` and  `Objects.hashCode("z", "z")` is between 4065 and 4865 which doesn't look particularly uniform, esp for the higher bits.

Within this context, I think you can say you are not making matters any worse.

Comment: If so. which way is better to avoid negative value of hashcode()
1. as above 
2. avoid negative value at this step: arr[h+i % h] = k. I mean I use Math.abs(h+i % h) to convert to positive value.

Comment: @nd07 You want to avoid `Math.abs` here as this can return a negative number o_O The `(hash & 0x7FFF_FFFF) % buckets` is better. Note: `Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE) == Integer.MIN_VALUE` which you are unlikely to find out for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

Please have look in to [***Murmurhash***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash)
and [MurmurHash - what is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899616/murmurhash-what-is-it)
Fortunately Google guava has ready made implementation for this.

Guava way is like below  example
We have following classes

`import com.google.common.hash.HashCode;
 import com.google.common.hash.HashFunction;
 import com.google.common.hash.Hashing;`

using the above classes I have my method to generate hashcode like below

```
/**
     * getMurmur128Hash.
     * 
     * @param content
     * @return HashCode
     */
    public static HashCode getMurmur128Hash(String content) {
        final HashFunction hf = Hashing.murmur3_128();
        final HashCode hc = hf.newHasher().putString(content, Charsets.UTF_8).hash();
        return hc;
    }
    /**
     * getAbsMurmur128HashAsLongVal.
     * 
     * @param content
     * @return Long Absolute value of Long for the HashCode.
     */
    public static Long getAbsMurmur128HashAsLongVal(String content) {
        return Math.abs(getMurmur128Hash(content).asLong());
    }
```